# DocX c# library merging table fields in a row

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I am working with DocX, a library for creating Microsoft `.docx` files from C#. https://docx.codeplex.com/

I need to merge some tables inside same row. I already figured out how to merge them inside a column.

```
var doc = DocX.Load(fileName);
Table t3 = doc.AddTable(39, 11);

t3.Alignment = Alignment.center;
t3.Design = TableDesign.TableGrid;

t3.MergeCellsInColumn(0, 0, 9);
doc.InsertTable(t3);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Row row = table.InsertRow();
```

if use: `row.MergeCells(0, 3);`
 It merge both column and row

So, can use to remove rows empty

```
                row.Cells[0].RemoveParagraphAt(3);
                row.Cells[0].RemoveParagraphAt(2);
                row.Cells[0].RemoveParagraphAt(1);
```

and use : `table.MergeCellsInColumn(2, 1, 1);`
 Only merge rows in a column

Comment: Good shout for removing the empty paragraphs left over by the merged cells.

Answer (score 4):

To merge cells inside a row you need to define the row first. A bitt different than in Colums where you define the colum inside the function.

```
t2.Rows[0].MergeCells(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Set font use Docx.dll:

```
FontFamily font = new FontFamily("Times New Roman");
Row row = table.InsertRow();
row.Paragraphs[0].Font(font).FontSize(13);
```